# Why is the Binding of the Point3DCollection not working?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

**Hey there,**

the generation of my Point3DCollection works fine and i get the Mesh in the Viewport3D (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRAo.jpg), but the calculateNoise() doesnt update my bound Positions in the Viewport3D even though the OnPropertyChanged Method in my ViewModel get's called. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance, 
KonstIT

XAML:

```
<Viewport3D>
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <Model3DGroup>
                <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1, -1, -3" />
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="{Binding Positions}" TriangleIndices="{Binding TriangleIndices}"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial Brush="White"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </Model3DGroup>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

ViewportViewModel:

```
 internal class ViewportViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     private int _terrainSize;
     private Point3DCollection _positions;
     private Int32Collection _triangleIndices;
     private Random random = new Random();

     public Point3DCollection Positions
        {
            get
            {
                return _positions;
            }
            set
            {
                _positions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Positions");
            }
        }
     public Int32Collection TriangleIndices
        {
            get
            {
                return _triangleIndices;
            }
            set
            {
                _triangleIndices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TriangleIndices");
            }
        }

     public ViewportViewModel()
     {
         _terrainSize = 56;
         _positions = new Point3DCollection();
         _triangleIndices = new Int32Collection();
         GeneratePositions();
         GenerateTriangleIndices();
         CalculateNoiseCommand = new CalculateNoiseCommand(this);
     }

     private void GeneratePositions()
        { //Works }

     private void GenerateTriangleIndices()
        { //Works }

     //Handling
     ...

     internal void CalculateNoise()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < _terrainSize * _terrainSize; i++)
         {
             Point3D point = new Point3D();
             point = Positions[i];
             point.Y = random.Next(10) / 10.0;
             Positions[i] = point;
         }
         OnPropertyChanged("Positions");
     }

     #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                Console.WriteLine("ViewportViewModel: " + propertyName);
            }
        }

        #endregion

 }
```

The Code to replace the current Point3DCollection. It's the same as the GeneratePositions() which is called at the constructor, just with the Positions.Clear() method at the beginning. It's called via the CalculateNoise().

```
        private void ReplacePositions()
        {
            if(Positions.Count > 0)
            {
                Positions.Clear();
            }

            var column = 0;
            var row = 0;
            Point3D point = new Point3D();

            for (int i = 0; i < _terrainSize * _terrainSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                        point.X = ((float)column / ((float)_terrainSize - 1) - 0.5) * 2;
                    if (j == 1)
                        point.Y = 0;
                    if (j == 2)
                        point.Z = ((float)row / ((float)_terrainSize - 1) - 0.5) * 2;
                }

                Positions.Add(point);

                // Calculate next row & column
                column++;
                if (column % _terrainSize == 0)
                {
                    row++;
                }
                column %= _terrainSize;
            }
        }

        internal void CalculateNoise()
        {
            ReplacePositions();
            OnPropertyChanged("Positions");
        }
```

Comment: this question is too broad...please  be more specific
what did you try where are you stuck?

Comment: Expose the Point3DCollection as a property of a viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Let's call that property `Points`. Bind it appropriately in the XAML. When you change a point in the collection, call `PropertyChanged(nameof(Points))` so the binding will know it needs to update the target property.

Comment: Hey @Ed Plunkett, 
thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesnt work :( 
Binding in XAML: `Positions="{Binding Points, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` and the method i call in my viewModel actually calls the OnPropertyChanged method of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. But somehow it doesnt update the Point3DCollection which is bound to the Viewport3D

Comment: 1) Please don't add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` until you've read and understood the documentation on it. 2) Please show the code that's not working. If the binding works at all, it should be an easy fix.

Comment: Hey @Ed Plunkett ,

i changed the generell Question and updated the code. Theres now the XAML part which is fine i guess and the viewModel where something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that when you call `CalculateNoise()`, the UI doesn't reflect the changed information in `Positions`? If so, it's possible that the control is ignoring the change because it's seeing the same collection object as before, so it assumes the points will e the same. You could test that theory by creating a new `Point3DCollection` in `CalculateNoise()`, populating that, and assigning it to `Positions`. I probably should have suggested that in the first place.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. Also if i'm adding or removing a Point3D. Whilst the Position Property in the ViewModel do have the new values. The Viewport3D binding doesn't get updated.

Comment: Can you show me the code that replaces `Positions` with a new collection?

Comment: I added it to the end of the question. Thanks for taking the time to look over these.

Comment: Nothing in that code replaces `Positions` with a new collection. You clear the existing collection and then you add new items to it. It's the same object, the same instance of `Point3DCollection`. You have not replaced it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class GeometryTips : ViewModelBase
{
    #region " Private Fields "
    private int _terrainSize = 56;
    private Random random = new Random();
    #endregion

    #region " Public Properties "

    #region " MeshGeo "
    private MeshGeometry3D _MeshGeo;
    public MeshGeometry3D MeshGeo
    {
        get { return _MeshGeo; }
        set { this.Set(ref _MeshGeo, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region " Commands "

    #region " Create3DCommand "
    public RelayCommand Create3DCommand { get; private set; }
    private void Create3D()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _terrainSize * _terrainSize; i++)
        {
            Point3D point = new Point3D();
            point = MeshGeo.Positions[i];
            point.Y = random.Next(10) / 10.0;
            MeshGeo.Positions[i] = point;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region " Constructor "
    /// <summary>
    /// GeometryTips
    /// </summary>
    public GeometryTips()
    {
        this.Create3DCommand = new RelayCommand(Create3D);
        this._MeshGeo = new MeshGeometry3D();
        GeneratePositions();
        GenerateTriangleIndices();
    }
    #endregion

    #region " Private Functions "

    #region " GeneratePositions "
    /// <summary>
    /// GeneratePositions
    /// </summary>
    private void GeneratePositions()
    {

        var column = 0;
        var row = 0;
        Point3D point = new Point3D();

        for (int i = 0; i < _terrainSize * _terrainSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    point.X = ((float)column / ((float)_terrainSize - 1) - 0.5) * 2;
                if (j == 1)
                    point.Y = 0;
                if (j == 2)
                    point.Z = ((float)row / ((float)_terrainSize - 1) - 0.5) * 2;
            }
            _MeshGeo.Positions.Add(point);

            // Calculate next row & column
            column++;
            if (column % _terrainSize == 0)
            {
                row++;
            }
            column %= _terrainSize;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region " GenerateTriangleIndices "
    /// <summary>
    /// GenerateTriangleIndices
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateTriangleIndices()
    {
        var value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _terrainSize * _terrainSize - _terrainSize; i++)
        {
            for (int triangle = 0; triangle < 3; triangle++)
            {
                if (i % _terrainSize == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (triangle == 0)
                {
                    value = i;
                }
                else if (triangle == 1)
                {
                    value = i + triangle + _terrainSize - 2;
                }
                else if (triangle == 2)
                {
                    value = i + triangle + _terrainSize - 2;
                }
                _MeshGeo.TriangleIndices.Add(value);
            }
            for (int triangle = 0; triangle < 3; triangle++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && ((i + 1) % _terrainSize) == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (triangle == 0)
                {
                    value = i + triangle;
                }
                else if (triangle == 1)
                {
                    value = i + triangle + _terrainSize - 1;
                }
                else if (triangle == 2)
                {
                    value = i + triangle - 1;
                }
                _MeshGeo.TriangleIndices.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

I created this viewmodel with MVVM Light.

I use a MeshGeometry3D class to bind against.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewport3D Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <DirectionalLight Direction="-1, -1, -3"/>
                    <GeometryModel3D Geometry="{Binding MeshGeo}">
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="White"/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Handle" Command="{Binding Create3DCommand}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

This was working for me, hope it helps...